# Kafka Streams bulk entry update/delete by Punctuator

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stateful Kafka Streams app, and I need to implement regular deletions based on a condition.
I've come up with a solution based on the ProcessorAPI which is explained in documentation, but looks like I'm missing the intuition here, so I'm having some doubts.

I have bunch of streams like this for every StateStore I create during the app initialization:

```
    private void doStuff(KStream<String, ExampleObject> sourceStream, 
         Materialized<String, ExampleObject, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized, String tableName) {   
         KTable<String, ExampleObject> ktable = sourceStream.groupByKey()
                                   .aggregate(() -> null, (id, newValue, existingValue) -> {...}, materialized);
         ktable.toStream().process(new PunctuatorProcessorSupplier(tableName), tableName);                             
    }
```

And I have this Processor (I omit the Supplier for shortness because the implementation is trivial, it just returns new Processor every time)

```
private static class PunctuatorProcessor implements
    Processor<String, ExampleObject> {

    private final String stateStoreName;
    
    private Cancellable cancellable;

    private PunctuatorProcessor(String stateStoreName) {
        this.stateStoreName = stateStoreName;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        KeyValueStore<String, ExampleObject> stateStore = 
            (KeyValueStore<String, ExampleObject>) context.getStateStore(this.stateStoreName);
        this.cancellable = context.schedule(Duration.ofDays(1),
            PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, getPunctuator(stateStore));
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, ExampleObject value) {
        
    }

    private static Punctuator getPunctuator(KeyValueStore<String, ExampleObject> stateStore) {
        return timestamp -> {
            try (final KeyValueIterator<String, ExampleObject> iter = stateStore.all()) {
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    final KeyValue<String, ExampleObject> entry = iter.next();
                    if (some condition) {
                        // Update the object.
                        stateStore.put(entry.key, entry.value);
                        // OR delete the object.
                        stateStore.delete(entry.key);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.cancellable.cancel();
    }
}
```

Now the questions:

1. Is this a legit usage of the ProcessorAPI in my case? Or do I need to use `Topology.addProcessor()`? Or are those two are essentially the same?
2. Do I need to commit anything?
3. I'm doing `Ktable.toStream()` since `process()` is a terminal operation. Do I just need to use `transformValues()` instead and put it somewhere before aggregate()? As I understand, `transform` is stateful unlike `process`, how does this affect the performance? Will it change the existing topology and corrupt the changelog topic because of that?
4. Since I only care about accessing the StateStore, do I need to do anything in the `process()` method?
5. Is there any performance difference between STREAM_TIME and WALL_CLOCK_TIME? Let's suppose with my data they are going to go side by side, so it's not the question if one happens more often than the other, I mean, are they are managed by the same thread as the task, or are there any quirks?
6. Is the operation in Punctuator going to update the changelog topic too?
7. Is adding that kind of operation to an existing stateful app considered a change in topology, and will it corrupt the existing data?

Thank you!
=====UPDATE======
I use the following code to check if update is happening in the stateStore, and I see that the Punctuator always receives the value that's not updated. So the update is either not written or lost.

The timestamped stateStore is returned from the context:

```
public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    KeyValueStore<String, ValueAndTimestamp<ExampleObject>> stateStore = 
        (KeyValueStore<String, ValueAndTimestamp<ExampleObject>>) context.getStateStore(this.stateStoreName);
    this.cancellable = context.schedule(Duration.ofMinutes(5),
        PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, getPunctuator(stateStore, stateStoreName, context));
}
```

Then I read, update and then I read again and the logger logs unchanged value:

```
    private Punctuator getPunctuator(KeyValueStore<String, ValueAndTimestamp<ExampleObject>> stateStore) {
        return timestamp -> {
            try (final KeyValueIterator<String, ValueAndTimestamp<ExampleObject>> iter = stateStore.all()) {
                String testId = "someId";
                logger.info("Punctuator started with stateStore {}", stateStoreName);
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    final KeyValue<String, ValueAndTimestamp<ExampleObject>> entry = iter.next();
                    String key = entry.key;
                    if (testId.equals(key)) {
                        ExampleObject value = entry.value.value();
                        logger.info(
                            "PunctuatorProcessor in action, storeName {} testId {}, current ExampleObject {}",
                            stateStoreName, key, value);
                        boolean stripped = stripElement(value);
                        logger.info(
                            "PunctuatorProcessor in action, storeName {} testId {}, found and stripped: {}",
                            stateStoreName, key, stripped);
                        if (stripped) {
                            stateStore.put(key, ValueAndTimestamp.make(value, context.timestamp()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

;
        }
```

Why the value is always unchanged? The punctuator Duration is 10 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are multiple questions it's best to answer one by one:

1. Is this a legit usage of the ProcessorAPI in my case? Or do I need to use Topology.addProcessor()? Or are those two are essentially the same? **It is a legit use of processor API to clean up your state stores. In fact that's pretty much the way to do it. One thing to be mindful of is that if the time taken to iterate through the whole store will be longer than task timeout it will cause your app to crash. Process() method under the hood does pretty much Topology.addProcessor() so this is all.**
2. Do I need to commit anything? **No you do not. You are not forwarding any records so if your use case is a store clean up this is it.**
3. I'm doing Ktable.toStream() since process() is a terminal operation. Do I just need to use transformValues() instead and put it somewhere before aggregate()? As I understand, transform is stateful unlike process, how does this affect the performance? Will it change the existing topology and corrupt the changelog topic because of that? **`process` is a terminal operation in versions of KafkaStreams before 3.3.x. In these versions utilize the `transform` operation. Your transform operation is stateful (because of attaching a store), but overall it doesn't have to be stateful. The statefulness of your operations doesn't impact performance here since you are not publishing new messages, or repartitioning. It will not hurt your topology, but it may cause a small change to it. If you'd like to compare topologies use `describe` method and compare them. However it will impact overall message processing, since while the punctuator is running messages are not processed in the subtopology (other processors are not running).**
4. Since I only care about accessing the StateStore, do I need to do anything in the process() method? **If you are using `process` it is terminal, and no further work needs to be done. If you were to use `transform` you'd need to forward incoming records, otherwise they would simply be lost. This operation is performed using `context.forward()` method.**
5. Is there any performance difference between STREAM_TIME and WALL_CLOCK_TIME? Let's suppose with my data they are going to go side by side, so it's not the question if one happens more often than the other, I mean, are they are managed by the same thread as the task, or are there any quirks? **I'd start here: [link](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/PunctuationType.html). But long story short: wall clock time advances always (it's the one you want for your case), but the stream time advances only when records arrive. So if you had a stream that rarely had anything published to it your punctuator wouldn't run on time.**
6. Is the operation in Punctuator going to update the changelog topic too? **Yes. All local state stores are backed by changelog topics, so tombstones will be published to the topic.**
7. Is adding that kind of operation to an existing stateful app considered a change in topology, and will it corrupt the existing data? **It is a change to topology since you are adding a processor. It will not corrupt data, since you are not changing the objects published to Kafka. Also if you were publishing JSON objects there wouldn't be data corruption, but in case of Avro or Protobuf.**

Overall your code looks solid, I would be a little worried about the punctuator taking a lot of time, because it will stop the processing of messages for the subtopology as long as it runs.

Comment: Thank you! Would it be acceptable to spawn a separate thread in the Punctuator to clean up the store? I'm thinking no because that would assume concurrent modification of the values and hence, possible inconsistency. Otherwise what options do I have to avoid blocking the topology?

Comment: From what I see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318983/is-processorcontext-schedule-thread-safe spawning a new thread is not possible

Comment: It is not, your threading model is limited by what KafkaStreams allows. Hence you have one thread per subtopology. Also if you did that (somehow) you run the risk of ConcurrentModificationException. You can use the range operator to clean up in batches though.

Comment: So I deployed the code and I'm seeing that the when I do `put()` then during the next punctuation if 5 mins I'm reading the value unchanged. Do you think there's anything I can look into to understand what's happening? Thank you.

Comment: the problem is that the store I recieve from the context is KeyValueIterator<String, ValueAndTimestamp<ExampleObject>>.
I don't understand how to right back to this store. If I just write the same value as I get supposing that the underlying ExampleObject is written with the changes since it's passed by reference, then when I read it it's unchanged. Any thoughts?

Comment: The store will store exactly what you put in there. If you've not deleted the object your punctuator will iterate the whole store. I'd suggest TopologyTestDriver to see it in action under a debugger perhaps.

Comment: What I'm saying is I'm modifying the object doing put instead of delete. And this has not effect, so there's something wrong.

Comment: What are you using to verify that the object has been updated? Interactive queries? Store retrieved by TopologyTestDriver? Logging? As far as I can tell your code should work. Please note that aggregate does not propagate tombstones, so if you depend on them for your deletion this might never happen.

Comment: I've updated the post with the code on how I check the value. I think it doesn't matter if I write a test if when deployed in Kubernetes I'm seeing unchanged value always after updating the store... I wonder what can be wrong?

Comment: If you are sure your punctuator runs (I see it run every 5 minutes), then check if the changelog topic has the updated messages. If it does maybe your persistent state store does not have the ability to write to the disk (for example due to user permissions). As I mentioned earlier code looks fine. Did you try testing with TestContainers?

Comment: I did not try testing with TestContainers yet. How do I check the changelog topic?

Comment: I'm also seeing that I'm able to write to one of the state stores but not to another. This means that it's not a matter of container permissions. How can I debug this?

Comment: It might be an issue with either topic permissions - check the broker logs then - you should see at least an exception in there. Or it may be an issue with volume permissions - should see an issue in kafka streams app logs.

Comment: No exceptions I'm seeing... Will continue digging